# How to use numbers just as a description in Specflow Feature file instead of a parameter

Tags: specflow, gherkin, feature-file

I'm writing my feature file SpecFlow and I'm looking to use numbers as a just a description.
For example :

```
Given Site is displayed
When I check column1
And column2  
Then values are correct.
```

However in the word column1, 1 is actually read as a parameter instead of a description and the method generated for the line is column(.*) instead of column1. And because of this, since I have another line for column2, only 1 method is generated for then "When" & "And" statement.

This is incorrect as I would need to check the elements for both column1 and column2. Is there a way for us to just use numbers as description in the feature file instead of parameters?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"the word column1, 1 is actually read as a parameter instead of a description"*? What do you mean by "description"? Do you want `column1` to be a string parameter to your step definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either modify the step definition or surround the column name in double quotes.

**Option A) Modify the step definition:**

```cs
[When(@"I check ([^ ]+)$")]
public void WhenICheckColumn(string columnName)
{
    // Check the column
}
```

**Option B) Surround column name in double quotes**

Change the step itself:

```
When I check "column1"
```

Then change the step definition to:

```cs
[When(@"I check ""(.*)""")]
public void WhenICheckColumn(string columnName)
{
    // Check the column
}
```

Comment: Thanks Greg! Passing the parameter as a string instead of an integer is just what I needed